# Discarding changes in working directory made it untracked. How do I retrack it?

Tags: git

I did "git checkout -- filename.java" to discard any changes to the file and now when I do "git status", it shows up as an untracked file. Why did that happen and how can I make it so that it remains a tracked file with no changes made from master branch?

Thank you.

Comment: It sorta depends on how your working branch and master differed in the first place. Since this isn't expected behavior, we'd be guessing. Did that file exist in your branch when it was created?

Comment: Ok, that was dumb. I figured out that the file didn't exist in the branch in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to re-add it do `git add filename`